# how to enable ipv6 in redhat

Tags: ipv6, linux-kernel

can anyone tell me how to enable ipv6 support in  rhel
i tried
sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
and
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/conf/all/forwarding
and did
service network restart
but still i get error

Bringing up interface eth0:  Global IPv6 forwarding is enabled in configuration
, but not currently enabled in kernel

can anyone please help